# How to compare the received data with another data to show only the data that I need using Angular 2+?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, model

I hope this is not duplicated =).

I want to know How to compare the received data with another data to show only the data that I need using Angular 2+?

I mean, I get data from a service and I show it in a list with `*ngFor` in this case, 4 objects only shows me 3 which are the ones within the model used but I open a modal that has an input that makes a request to another service with another model and returns in this case, 4 objects to enter in that list.
.

In my case, there are 4 users in the user database, 3 are inside a group and 1 is not in that gruop, when I open the modal and I do the request to get all the users (4 in this case), I want to filter the only one that is not inside that group.

Here is my first model (sorry for Spanglish).

```
export class AplicacionAccesoUsuario {
  public id_Aplicacion: number;
  public id_Usuario: number;
  public admin: boolean;
  public aplicacion: AplicacionModel;
  public usuario: UserDataModel;
  public selected: any;

}
```

Here is my second model

```
export class UserDataModel {

  public id_Entidad: number;
  public id_Usuario: number;
  public userName: string;
  public fechaBaja: Date;
  public nombre: string;
  public foto: any;

}
```

and some Images.

- [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p90G1.jpg)
- [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPAYQ.jpg)

In this case If I add an user that exist in the list (janco, helios, alexis) it will get an error, I need to recibe all the users and compare it with the users in the first list to show only the user that is not in the list (in this case WS CMA).

I hope you have understood me, thank you very much =).